# I want to disprove an equality involving a double integral

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, integral-transforms, integration

I want to show that the following equality does not hold:

\begin{equation}\label{at3}
    \frac{\lambda^2-1}{2}x^2-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(y_1,y_2,x)\ln g(y_1,y_2)dy_2dy_1=\mbox{constant}\ \ ,\ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
where $\lambda>1$, and
\begin{equation}\label{at2}
    g(y_1,y_2)=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-\frac{(\lambda^2-1)u^2}{2}+\lambda y_1u}\cosh\left(y_2\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)dF(u),
\end{equation}
in which $F(u)$ is an unknown cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $U$ with the support $[-1,1]$. It could be discrete or continuous or a mixture. Finally,
\begin{align}
    K(y_1,y_2,x)=e^{-\frac{(\lambda^2-1)}{2}x^2}e^{\frac{-y_1^2-y_2^2+2\lambda y_1x}{2}}\cos \left(y_2\sqrt{x^2-1}\right).
\end{align}
In order to show that the first equality is not valid, I tried to see the scaling behaviour of the double integral term in $x$. I think that the double integral term is at most $O(x)$, so that it cannot cancel the effect of the first term $\frac{\lambda^2-1}{2}x^2$. However, I was not successful.

I highly appreciate your help about this problem.

Comment: this equality should hold for any $F(u)$?

Comment: I want to prove that it doesn't hold for any F(u). I mean any CDF with support [-1,1]

Comment: how about $\lambda$? should the equality hold for any $\lambda>1$? --- you may want to give some more background on this question, as a motivation.

Comment: Yes, for any $\lambda>1$. Actually, $\lambda$ can be viewed as a condition number of a matrix. When it is 1, the equality that I want to disprove holds.  I want to show that otherwise, it should not hold. I will send you and email for the further details.

Comment: Ok, I can refer you to this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.03779.pdf, where the authors consider a point to point parallel Gaussian channel. See Section II on system model. The gain of the stronger branch is $\lambda$, and the gain of the weaker branch is 1. both of the branches undergo additive white Gaussian noise, which is the very reason for the exponentials you see. They are due to the Gaussian nature of the additive noise.

Comment: forgive me for asking, but isn't your statement proven in the paper you just referred me to?

Comment: Well, I do not think the steps from (49) to (54) are rigorous.

Comment: but really, if this is your point, to question particular steps in a derivation from the literature, shouldn't you disclose that here? now you risk that users waste time repeating a calculation that can be found online, rather than focusing on a specific difficulty you have encountered in that derivation.

Comment: The thing is that if I question a specific step in a derivation then the reader takes that derivation for granted, and is restricted only in that framework. However, maybe the very reason that the paper is still on arxiv and not published, is the wrong approach taken to divide the double integral into 3 parts and taking the limit of the boundaries. Then, why would I force the reader to follow similar steps first and then answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly I am not understanding the question, and you will correct me. You say for $\lambda=1$ the equality holds for any $F(u)$ on $[-1,1]$. Let me try $dF(u)=\delta(u-1)du$, so
$$g(y_1,y_2)=e^{y_1},\;\;
    K(y_1,y_2,x)=\exp\left(\frac{-y_1^2-y_2^2+2 y_1x}{2}\right)\cos \left(y_2\sqrt{x^2-1}\right),$$
and hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(y_1,y_2,x)\ln g(y_1,y_2)dy_2dy_1=2\pi x\sqrt e\neq\text{constant}.
$$

Comment: Sorry if I could not explain it thoroughly. For $\lambda = 1$, there exists a distribution, or a $F(u)$, such that the equality holds. Of course, not for every $F(u)$, but there exists one. However, I want to say if $\lambda >1$, no such distribution exists. So, any distribution that you choose will not make the left hand side a constant.